# Find the number of elements $a^{x}=x$ depending on $ a> 0 $

Tags: real-analysis

**My try**
Let $$f(x)=a^{x}-x=e^{x\cdot ln a}-x$$
So $$f'(x)=a^{x-1}\cdot x-1$$
Then I should examine the $ f $ monotonicity.
But when I can do it I have:
$$f'(x)>0$$
$$a^{x-1}\cdot x>1$$However I don't know what can I do in this moment. I tried:
for $x>0$: $(x-1)lna>-lnx$ but I still do not know how to get to zero places $ f '(x) $.
Can you get some tips how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have differentiated $a^{x}$ wrongly. It should be $a^{x}\ln(a)$. But I suggest you sketch the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=a^{x}$ on the same axes and consider the number of intersections, and the conditions on $a$ for there to be any intersections at all.

Comment: why do you think that wrongly? $f'(x)=e^{x\cdot lna}\frac{x}{a}=a^{x-1}x$. Moreover I mustn't use the graphs - I must use calculus

Comment: a is a constant not a variable. I understand your point about giving the final answer without using graphs, but still sketching the graphs may give you a hint how to proceed.